# Invincibility in "The Binding of Isaac Rebirth"

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

i wanted to ask you guys, if there is a way to be invincible in "The Binding Of Isaac Rebirth" (with an item combo).
I once heared about something with the *cursed scull*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Version:**

- The Wafer: Reduces every damage to half a heart
- The Habit: fills up the Spacebar item by one if hit
- Yum Heart: 4 bars, gives 1 red heart
- Scapular: if at half a heart, gain 1 soul heart

**So basically you can't die. Lets say Yum Heart is empty and you have 1 1/2 hearts left:**

- Take 2 hits, drop to half a heart -> Scapular activated, gain one soul heart
- Another two hits, soul heart gone, yum heart full
- Start with step 1

Of course, you have to be quick with the Yum Heart, but this is pretty much the best invincibility combo in the game.

**2. Version (even better)**

- Sharp Plug: If your Spacebar item is empty, it will become fully charged at the cost of 2 hearts
- Blank Card: Copies the effect of your current card
- XIX The Sun (Card): Reveals the current floor, damages enemies and heals you.

With this powerful Setup, you have unlimited hearts and you can clear rooms quickly. This works forever if you don' drop below 2.5 hearts since you can just activate the blank card at 2.5 hearts and will be fully restored thanks to the sun. You can also spam spacebar in order to activate multiple sun cards in a row, which can clear rooms quite quickly.

#### Other Options, even though not that strong:

- Kamikaze + Pyromaniac: Heal without cooldown
- Gnawed Leaf + Any self attacking follower (Daddy Longlegs or Super Meat Boy): Kills everything while you go get some tea
- Cursed Skull + Scapular (+ The Wafer): Before you die, you'll be ported out of the room with an additional soul heart. Huge drawback if you are below womb where everything deals one damage, so you have to finish every room without getting hit ... the wafer makes this combo better too because you can get hit once.

Can't think of anything which made me really invincible ... maybe I'll edit this post if I remember something else.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser! So there isn't an actual combo to get invincible? Because enemy champions do 1 full heart of damage which would end the forst you mentioned.

Comment: Champions only deal 0.5 hearts if you have the wafer, so this will work fine on any level, no matter if you face a champion or if you are below Womb. Champions are a problem if you have cursed skull + scapular, because you have to finish every room without taking damage.

Comment: oh, i forgot that^^ thx

Comment: @Lumisch Not a problem, you're welcome. :)

Comment: Pyro plus soy Milk plus ipecac works too.

Comment: @Arperum Well, kinda ... if you're at half a heart, running behind the ipecacs is a bit risky ... I'd probably prefer soy milk and dr. fetus, since so many bombs can form a "wall" between you and walking enemies.

Comment: The thing is that ipecac is healing you. And with the soymilk speed that means crazy gast healing.

Comment: @Arperum Ipecac only heals you with Pyromaniac. And if you have Pyromaniac, Bombs heal you too (actually, any form of explosion will)

Comment: I know, and pyro, soy Milk and ipecac gives a *lot* of healing in no time, while also blowing up everything.

Comment: Another case is *Gnawed Leaf* + *The Ludovico Technique*. With *Brimstone* or Azazel even better.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any combos (like the one that Y U NO WORK told about) But there are actually items in-game that grant temporary invincibility (with some items having a longer duration than others). I assume that you probably know this, but in case you didn't, just a little extra info for you then :3